# How Would I input a variable in a javascript script that posts data to a php script?

Tags: javascript, variables

Here's my code:

```
  window.setInterval(function(){
  new Image().src = 'http://urltophp/p.php?
  c='+somevar;'&log_owner=testing&client_site='anothervar;
    somevar = '';
    anothervar = '';
  }, 1000);
```

How would I go about inserting a javascript variable ("somevar" and "anothervar"), into the url that I'm calling?

I can get it to work like...

```
'http://urltophp/p.php?c='+somevar;
```

But I can't get it to work with two vars at different locations in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate your javascript variable to, url string, as

```
new Image().src = 'http://urltophp/p.php?c='+somevar
                   +'&log_owner=testing&client_site='+anothervar;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `+` to connect all the parts that make up the url, i.e., between each variable and string literal, and don't put a semicolon in the middle of the statement like you have after `somevar`. So instead of:

```
new Image().src = 'http://urltophp/p.php?
c='+somevar;'&log_owner=testing&client_site='anothervar;
```

Try:

```
new Image().src = 'http://urltophp/p.php?c=' + somevar +
                  '&log_owner=testing&client_site=' + anothervar;
```

Also you can't put a line break in the middle of a string literal like you have right after `php?`, but maybe that's just a typo in your question? You *can* put line breaks after operators like `+`, or after variable names.

Comment: I'm a PHP programmer, just wasn't thinking out side of the box. lol.